# How to get the next record in a Table using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

UPDATE: next button still not working.
I had to change some of the code because my next button was going from id 1, to 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. If a JobSeekerProfile record was deleted, then I have an issue where let's say in my table I had records with id's 1-10 and then 15, and then 29 because I was removing people's profiles and testing things out, because of this it was showing the wrong profiles for some of the users. I've managed to fix this issue, but now my next route or button isn't working anymore, it's not moving to the next id in the job_seekers_profiles table.

Here is my modified code from my controller AdminEmployerSearchController.php:

```
class AdminEmployerSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $jobSeekerProfiles = JobSeekerProfile::where('id', 1)->get();

        $employerProfile = EmployerProfile::all()->where('id', $user->id)->first();

        $jobSeekerProfileNewId = JobSeekerProfile::all()->where('id', $id);

        $video1 = Video::all()->where('id', $jobSeekerProfiles[0]->video_one_id)->first();;

        $video2 = Video::all()->where('id', $jobSeekerProfiles[0]->video_two_id)->first();;

        $video3 = Video::all()->where('id', $jobSeekerProfiles[0]->video_three_id)->first();;

        return view('admin.employer.search.show', compact('jobSeekerProfiles', 'employerProfile', 'video1', 'video2', 'video3', 'jobSeekerProfileNewId'));
    }

    public function next($id)
    {

        $jobSeekerProfiles = JobSeekerProfile::skip($id)->take($id)->limit(1)->get();

        return view('admin.employer.search.show', compact('jobSeekerProfiles'));
    }
}
```

Modified blade file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>My Profile</h1>
        <video width="100%" height="100%" controls style="margin-top: 0;">
            {{--                <source src="highrjobs/storage/app/public/videos/{{ $videos[0] ? $videos[0]->file : '' }}" type="video/mp4">--}}
            <source src="http://highrjobs.test/storage/app/public{{ $video1->file ?? '' }}" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <br><br><br>
        <h1 class="h1-admin">{{$jobSeekerProfileNewId->first()->first_name}} {{$jobSeekerProfileNewId->first()->last_name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <br><br><br>
        <video width="100" height="auto" controls>
            <source src="http://highrjobs.test/storage/app/public{{ $video2->file ?? '' }}" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <video width="100" height="auto" controls>
            <source src="http://highrjobs.test/storage/app/public{{ $video3->file ?? '' }}" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Experience:</h3>
        <p>{{$jobSeekerProfileNewId->first()->experience}}</p>
        <h3>Additional Skills:</h3>
        <p>{{$jobSeekerProfileNewId->first()->additional_skills}}</p>
    </div>
    @if(Auth::user()->role_id === 2)
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger">Skip</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Request an Interview</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="height: 340px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Request an Interview</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Select 2 options for your availabilities:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="display: inline-flex;">

                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminEmployerInterviewRequestsController@store', 'files'=>true, 'style'=>'width: 100%;']) !!}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                            {!! Form::text('date_time1', null, ['class'=> $errors->first('date_time1') ? 'border-danger form-control datetimepicker-input' : 'form-control datetimepicker-input', 'data-target'=>'#datetimepicker1']) !!}
                            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            </div><br>
                        </div>
                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('date_time1') }}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                            {!! Form::text('date_time2', null, ['class'=> $errors->first('date_time2') ? 'border-danger form-control datetimepicker-input' : 'form-control datetimepicker-input', 'data-target'=>'#datetimepicker2']) !!}
                            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            </div><br>
                        </div>
                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('date_time2') }}</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::hidden('job_seeker_profile_user_id', $jobSeekerProfileNewId->first()->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        {!! Form::submit('Send Interview Request', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary float-right']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br><br>

                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the next method in my controller not working anymore?

---

I have a Table in my database called job_seeker_profiles, where I store the profiles of those seeking a job. I have a controller called AdminEmployerSearchController, where Employers can view the profiles of the job seekers, with this show method:

```
public function show()
    {
        $jobSeekerProfiles = JobSeekerProfile::limit(1)->get();

        return view('admin.employer.search.show', compact('jobSeekerProfiles'));
    }
```

It's showing me the first record in the Table, which is what I want, to show one record at a time. I have a button in my view called 'Skip', where when clicked, I want it to show the next record in the database, right now its showing me record 1, so when clicked it would go to record 2, then record 3, then record 4 etc. It's like a Prev and Next functionality.

show.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

    @if($jobSeekerProfiles)

        @foreach($jobSeekerProfiles as $jobSeekerProfile)

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
                        <source src="{{ asset('videos/1583095973A man DJing an event.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br>
                    <h1 class="h1-admin">{{$jobSeekerProfile->first_name}} {{$jobSeekerProfile->last_name}}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                    <br>
                    <video width="100" height="auto" controls>
                        <source src="{{ asset('videos/1583095973Man Doing Rap Music.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                    <video width="100" height="auto" controls>
                        <source src="{{ asset('videos/1583095973Tractor Cutting Grass In The Field.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Experience:</h3>
                    <p>{{$jobSeekerProfile->experience}}</p>
                    <h3>Additional Skills:</h3>
                    <p>{{$jobSeekerProfile->additional_skills}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger">Skip</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success">Interview</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br><br>
                    <hr><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endforeach

    @endif

@stop
```

I thought that I would have to find the id in the Table and then work with that, but I can't seem to get it working. Below is a screenshot of the page, you'll see what I mean.
[image]

Comment: You could use laravel's [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination). Or use `skip()` and `take()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `->skip()` or `->offset()` method to define the starting point, and `->take()` method to get number of data

```
JobSeekerProfile::get()->offset(2)->take(1);
```

Will return 3rd result skipping first 2 records.

Comment: I tried skip and take. It took me to the second record but then stopped. I’m not sure why.

Comment: @Ryan Sacks obviously, you have to make a controller and route with parameter so that, you can pass limit and offset anytime when next button is pressed. It will increase the ```->skip()``` parameter to give the next result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Pagination to do it:

```
$profiles = JobSeekerProfile::paginate(1);
return view('index', ['profiles' => $profiles]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

Comment: Was trying to figure out a way to do it without having the page numbers displayed, but thank you.

Comment: You can make a custom view that just has the next and back buttons from the results. Some thing like $profiles->nextPageUrl();